# ios designer constraints are not visible in Visual studio

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uistoryboard

In my native ios app am not able to see the constraints designer in `UIStoryBoard`.
am using `VisualStudio` for design `UIStoryBoard`. I want to add auto layout in that label but the constraints are not visible  [image]

Comment: I am also Experince the same thing some time ago. You have to `update the Visual Studio and iOS SDK `and check again it will work again..

Comment: Hi, is this problem resolved?

Comment: Yes am using Xcode for designing (: